# IIS Permissions or NTFS Permissions?

Tags: windows, iis-6

I currently have a Windows Server 2003 setup to serve multiple sites via IIS. One of our directories needs to allow access to only 1 specific AD Security Group.

I know there are two ways to accomplish this. One is using IIS to add permissions and the other is to set permissions on the folder/directory itself. A script runs at night and populates the content so users only need read permissions to view it in a browser.

My question is which one is preferred?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do both.  Turn off the anonymous user for the IIS website, and also lock down NTFS permissions to just the AD group + administrators + SYSTEM + the app pool user.

btw, the right-click permissions in IIS on the site level is the same NTFS permissions as if you do it from Windows Explorer directly.  It's just a shortcut to the same folder/file security settings.